# What is happening in the first episode of Black Rock Shooter?

Tags: black-rock-shooter

I've been trying to get into Black Rock Shooter but I can't get passes the first 3 episodes because I get really confused. Could someone explain what the first episode is about? It sorta goes all over the place and I'm not sure what they are trying to show.

Comment: Personally I don't think it has any meaning to it. It's just a pure action, no plot.

Comment: if you want BRS with plot just play PSP game version

Comment: it's been a while since i've seen the series but from what i remember it's revealed later on that BRS, Dead Master, Chariot and the like are "other selves" or the human characters and their fights match to what's happening in the real world, ie. Chariot detaining Dead Master = Kagari's possessiveness of Yomi. Chariot dropping Macaroons on the beaten BRS with Kagari;s voice saying "go home, go home" is from when Kagari was hostile to Mato visiting Yomi and Chariot carving that heart into Dead Master's chest is what heppened in the real world (when Kagari used a needle to carve it into Yomi)

Comment: (cont.) and it's later revealed that when people like Chariot and Dead Master are killed their real world selves loose their memories which later leads to the main crisis later on when which threatens the "other world" and revealing that there are human characters who are fully aware of their "other world" and it's nature

Answer (score -1):

They are showing fighthing between.... I suppose those creatures are something like mental entities or something at another dimension but still connected to the humans. When there's a problem with the main character, for example tension between her and her friend, the representation of them in another dimension are shown fighting. The story itself doesnt really make sense, but if you stick to the actual human character's story, i think it'll be more understandable and enjoyable.